# What is the BINARY operator equivalent in JPQL？

Tags: mysql, jpa, jpql

Is there any operator in **JPQL** equivalent to SQL **`BINARY`**?
I googled a lot and find no one mentions it.

Thanks in advance!

---

**For the BINARY operator, here's the description in [MySQL site](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/cast-functions.html#operator_binary).**

```
The BINARY operator casts the string following it to a binary string. 
This is an easy way to force a column comparison to be done byte by byte 
rather than character by character. This causes the comparison to be case 
sensitive even if the column is not defined as BINARY or BLOB. BINARY also 
causes trailing spaces to be significant.   

mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'A';  
        -> 1  
mysql> SELECT BINARY 'a' = 'A';  
        -> 0  
mysql> SELECT 'a' = 'a ';  
        -> 1  
mysql> SELECT BINARY 'a' = 'a ';  
        -> 0
```

BTY, I'm using MySql 5.6.(Though I don't think this problem is related to MySql...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still can't find the equivalent operator of **`BINARY`** in **JPQL**.
But there's a work around if you come across this problem :
In JPA, just use `em.createNativeQuery()` and you may use SQL and thus you can use `BINARY` operator.
Like this:

```
em.createNativeQuery("SELECT * FROM Student WHERE name=binary'"+ stuName+"'").getResultList();
```

Just provide those who have the same problem a solution.

Comment: This looks like a big SQL injection target!

Comment: You can create a native query, i. e. "SELECT * FROM Student WHERE BINARY name = ?" and then set the parameter with query.setParameter(1, stuName); - I tried some injections, but the parameter is escaped each time. However, I'd suggest further tests before using this productively.

Answer (score 0):

As of JPA 2.0 solution mentioned by @nosnhoj is the only solution which works until you want to change the collation of your database or table. I am not sure about JPA 2.1. Thanks for your help.